# Translating PHP Exceptions Messages

Tags: php, symfony, exception, laravel, translation

I'm using Symfony2 File Component, and it thrown an exception called "FileException".
The problem is the exception message is generated dinamically according to the error number, like so:

```
throw new FileException($this->getErrorMessage($this->getError()))
```

In the end I can get 6 distinct messages, so it seems to be impossible to translate or have custom messages displayed in catchs blocks.
I'd like to have something like this:

```
    catch (FileRequiredException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch (FileSizeException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch (FileExistsException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Does anybody have a solution for translating those dinamically generated exceptions messages?

Comment: Could you provide samples of these messages? I'm curious whether you could use a part of them for building translation keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try/Catch blocks won't work on Laravel, you must use its central error handler. You can do it by adding a something like this:

```
App::error(function(FileRequiredException $e)
{
    return View::make('yourErrorView')->with('message', $e->getMessage());
});
```

To your `app/filters.php` file.